# How to filter date in djangorestframwork?

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to filter the date from my model class but when i am passing the date from the URL its not filtering the dateTime. Here is my modal class:

```
class UserDeviceNotification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    mobile_device_id = models.ForeignKey(
        'UserMobileDevice',
        on_delete = models.CASCADE
    )
    notification_message = models.TextField()
    notification_title = models.TextField(null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.name
```

and

```
class UserNotificationDateFilterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.UserDeviceNotification
        fields = '__all__'

class FilterDateTime(django_filters.FilterSet):
    created_at = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(name="created_at",lookup_type="gte")

    class Meta:
        model = models.UserDeviceNotification
        fields = ['created_at']
```

View class :

```
class UserNotificationDateFilterAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = UserDeviceNotification.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = serializers.UserNotificationDateFilterSerializer
    pagination_class = PostLimitOffsetPagination
    filter_class = serializers.FilterDateTime

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

I have no clue what I am doing wrong here. But when I am passing the URL as :

> http://172.61.25.51:8080/api/user/filter_notification/?created_at=2019-07-17

I am not getting the filter response.

Comment: Did you set filter backends https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#setting-filter-backends ?

Comment: I forgot to add that. Now i am getting an error `_init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'`

Answer (score 1):

1. I guess we also need to add filter backend https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#setting-filter-backends
2. Filter doesn't have `name` field. Instead try `field_name` https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/5d1f6a512c0c8f092897bf805a3b3990451202e8/django_filters/filters.py#L69